# named routers in a single page application with angular (2/4)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web, single-page-application

I have an application in angular, it has a **login** component and then a **home** component that is the handler of all the SPA application, i have three more components called **users** that has add and edit actions.

this is part of the routing file:

```
 { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
 { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
 { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
 { path: 'users', component: UsersMenuComponent, canActivate: 
 [AuthGuard], outlet: 'userMenu'},
 { path: 'users/add', component: AddUserComponent, canActivate: 
 [AuthGuard] },
 { path: 'users/edit', component: EditUserComponent, canActivate: 
 [AuthGuard] },
 { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

In my app.component.html i have this:

```
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And this is part of the **home** component:

```
<div>
//code of the sidebar
</div>
<div>
//code of the navbar
</div>
<div class="col content">
 //this is where i don't know what to do
  <router-outlet name="userMenu"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

As you can see i set a name in the router outlet called userMenu and in the routing file i set it too the same name in the **UsersMenuComponent**

In this part is where im lost, i tried several ways to try that my named router shows the user component but i cant make it work.

1. in the html

   ```
   class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[{outlets: {'userMenu': ['users']}}]"
   ```
2. in the html with a variation:

   ```
   class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/users',{outlets: {'userMenu': ['users']}}]"
   ```
3. in a button

   ```
   this.router.navigate(['/users', {outlets: {'userMenu': ['users']}}]);
   ```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the UsersMenuComponent is a child of the HomeComponent Try

`{ path: 'home', 
   component: HomeComponent, 
   canActivate: [AuthGuard],
   children: [
    path: 'userMenu',
    component: UsersMenuComponent,
    outlet: 'userMenu'
  ] 
}`

then `this.router.navigate(['/home', { outlets: { userMenu: ['userMenu']}}]`

Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/6zh0aTEeWN0hEhRwF6Wt?p=info

Comment: Gave me the same error: when i click on the USERS option in the sidebar it kick me out into the  login page.

Comment: Created a plunker with a working sample https://plnkr.co/edit/6zh0aTEeWN0hEhRwF6Wt

Comment: Actually your answer help me to realize how to write properly the route, just with a little variation, thanks.